# Where does Postgres store all statistics?

Tags: postgresql, statistics

I recently ran into a weird problem while migrating from PG 9.4 => 11

I replicated the production server from PG 9.4 to PG 11 using `pglogical`. Everything worked out well, except we discovered that a few complex queries were taking tens of seconds on the PG 11 server, while there were taking under one second on the 9.4 server.

It turns out that running `ANALYZE` on the new server fixed the slow queries. So, I checked `$PGDATA/pg_stat` and `$PGDATA/pg_stat_tmp` and found them to be empty on **both** the servers!

Where does PG store statistics? (Follow-up question -- doesn't `pglogical` collect statistics while it is replicating?)

**Edit / follow-up:**

Output of query on `pg_stat_user_tables` on the new PG 11 server -

```
select analyze_count,autoanalyze_count, count(*) from pg_stat_user_tables group by 1,2;
 analyze_count | autoanalyze_count | count 
---------------+-------------------+-------
             1 |                11 |     1
             4 |                 7 |     1
             1 |                 0 |    14
             4 |                 0 |   168
(4 rows)
```

Same query on old PG 9.4 server (current production server):

```
 analyze_count | autoanalyze_count | count 
---------------+-------------------+-------
             0 |                13 |     3
             0 |               226 |     1
             0 |                 1 |    31
             0 |                 5 |     6
             0 |                21 |     2
             0 |                16 |     2
             0 |               601 |     1
             0 |                 8 |     1
             0 |                20 |     1
             0 |                 4 |     2
             0 |                 9 |     2
             0 |                10 |     2
             0 |                12 |     1
             0 |                 7 |     2
             0 |                41 |     1
             0 |                 2 |    11
             0 |                 6 |     1
             0 |                 3 |     8
             0 |               731 |     1
             0 |                39 |     1
             0 |                11 |     1
             0 |                 0 |    99
             0 |                50 |     1
             0 |                66 |     1
             0 |               241 |     1
             0 |                14 |     2
```

Comment: You have to [enable and install pg_stat_statements](https://pganalyze.com/docs/install/01_enabling_pg_stat_statements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two different kinds of statistics, and you are confusing them.  One is about the distributions of values in the table columns and things like that.  These are held in the table pg_catalog.pg_statistic, and the more-user-friendly view pg_stats. This is a more-or-less normal database table. These are gathered by ANALYZE and/or VACUUM, or their "auto" equivalents.

The other kind of statistics records how many updates, inserts, etc. have occured on each table. On a live server, you can see this data using the views `pg_stat_user_tables` and friends, but there are no real tables underlying these views. These statistics affect the first kind of statistics, because they are used to decide how often ANALYZE and VACUUM are auto-run. These are stored outside the normal database tables, in "pg_stats_tmp" (or whatever "stats_temp_directory" is set to if it is not the default) when the server is running, and moved to pg_stat for cold storage while the server is shut down.  Upon a crash, all this data is discarded. If both of these directories are empty, then perhaps you have turned "track_counts" off, or perhaps you have set "stats_temp_directory" to a non-default value and so are looking in the wrong place. Or maybe there was a crash recently and they have not been rebuilt yet.

> Follow-up question -- doesn't pglogical collect statistics while it is replicating?

If you have "track_counts" or "autovacuum" turned off, that would explain the lack of recent stats.  Or, if you populated the new database extremely quickly, then maybe the automatic analyze just didn't have a chance to do its things yet.  If none of those are the case, then you would have to consider whether there are no stats (of the pg_stats variety) at all, or if they existed but were just not fresh enough.  Running this query might help you figure that out:

```
select analyze_count,autoanalyze_count from pg_stat_user_tables
```

But there is a pretty good chance you will never be able to reach a definitive conclusion, unless you are willing to recreate the situation from scratch and poke around in it.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. I checked my PG config and indeed the pg_stat directory had been changed to - `stats_temp_directory = '/var/run/postgresql/11-main.pg_stat_tmp'`. And that directory indeed has some data.

Comment: I've confirmed that the following are enabled via this query: `select name, setting from pg_settings where name in ('autovacuum', 'track_activities', 'track_counts');`

Comment: running the query that you suggested, gives me zero rows - `select analyze_count,autoanalyze_count from pg_stat_user_tables;` -- is something misconfigured? how do I make sure that Postgres is configured to periodically collect statistics that are used by the query planner?

Comment: pg_stat_user_tables has no rows, or rows full of zeros?  If the first, are you connected to the correct database?  If the second, yes, something seems wrong.  Is this even after you manually ran ANALYZE?

Comment: You were correct. I was connected to the wrong DB. I've edited my question to add the output of the following query on both the server, i.e. PG 11 and PG 9.4 (current prod) - `select analyze_count,autoanalyze_count, count(*) from pg_stat_user_tables group by 1,2;` IIUC autoanalyze seems to be running more frequently on the old server compared to the new one. Why would this be the case?

Comment: autoanalyze is driven by activity counts, so if 9.4 is older and has seen more activity, it will have more autoanalyze.  Also, when you run manual ANALYZE it resets those counters itself, and so replaces some of the autoanalyze runs.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. IIUC autoanalyze should run along with autovacuum, right? Do I need to do anything special in my config to ensure that autoanalyze is enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You'll find a lot of informations on the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/monitoring-stats.html).

Particularly, you'll find informations about stored statistics in the `pg_stats` view (documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html)), but you'll need read permission on tables of your schema to be able to see data there. Don't forget to check you're connected to the right database.

Cheers,